# How can I add something after the day/hour/time in a date select list?

Tags: 8, datetime

On Drupal 8, the select list provided by the Date module looks like this:

[image: example select list]

The site I am building in Japanese, and in Japanese, it's common to add a character to indicate what the number means, like this:

```
2018 2 5 15 00　-> 2018年 2月 5日 15時 00分
```

How can I add these labels?  I attempted to do it through the string translation UI screen, but since the year, day, hour, and minutes are just numbers, there is no way to "translate" them.  The month shows up correctly because it is translated from Jan/Feb/etc.

I am thinking the solution involves `hook_form_alter()` but I don't know how to modify the way the values are displayed in the select widget without actually changing the values input and causing the form to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use **hook_form_alter()** or [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.2.x) in this case. Try with [hook_element_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.3.x)

```
function MY_MODULE_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['datelist'])) {
     $types['datelist']['#process'][] = '_mymodule_add_suffix_value';
  }
}

function _mymodule_add_suffix_value(&$element) {
  // process logic option $element['day']
  // process $element['month']
  // process $element['hour']
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code gives me a WSOD: 
`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\ProcessManager::process() must be of the type array, null given in Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\ProcessManager::process() (line 44 of themes/contrib/bootstrap/src/Plugin/ProcessManager.php).`

Comment: @PatrickKenny Just return $element at custom process function.